# Finitely generated module equal to free module of rank $n$? Not just the quotient of free module.

Tags: commutative-algebra, finitely-generated, free-modules

(For commutative algebra)

I have a Ring defined as the polynomial Ring over Field $K$: $R = K[x]$. I need to show that the finitely generated module $M$ is equal to a free module of rank $n$ for finite $n$. I can use the surjective function $f\colon R^n \to M$ to show that $M = R^n/\ker(f)$, but I am not sure how to get to the final result from here (that $M=R^n$).

Comment: This is quite false. Who gave you this assignment?

Comment: Are you sure you want free $R$-module not free $K$-module?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My lecturer, I didnt include that P has a special property as I thought it was irrelevant to this part, the entire question is: Let P be a module over a ring R with the following property. For any
surjective R-module homomorphism g : M −→N and any R-module homomorphism
f : P −→N , there exists an R-module homomorphism f ′ : P −→M such that f =
g ◦ f ′.

(2) If R = K[x] is the polynomial ring over a field K and P is finitely, show that
P = Rn for some finite n.

Comment: That hypothesis is essential; if it wasn't important it wouldn't be in the question. It is called projectivity. Use the structure theorem.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. < 3